# Terraform Error: At least one permission expected from permissions map

Tags: github, terraform

We manage our Github org through terraform and are getting the following error against many of our modules.

```
* module.product_tools.github_team_repository.write: 2 error(s) occurred:

* module.product_tools.github_team_repository.write[1]: github_team_repository.write.1: At least one permission expected from permissions map.
```

This occurred after we hit an abuse detection mechanism in Github which seemed to mess up our terraform state. I reverted back to an earlier version of the state file however I am now getting the above errors.

Anyone have any ideas about the permissions map?

Thanks!
Sinéad

Comment: It looks like it's saying that the user/token that's trying to read the Github repo doesn't have any permissions on the repo. Can you check whether that's the case?

Comment: Thanks @ydaetskcoR When I looked at the team permissions to the repos there was some sub-teams missing, I thought they were covered by the parent team, but when I specified them and re-ran terraform plan that worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: No worries. I've voted to close the question because it's not really reproducible for anyone else and is limited to your specific configuration that is not specifiable outside of this question.